# Are two sequences equal if the sums and sums of squares are equal?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Are two sequences $(x_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}$ and $(y_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}$ equal if $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=\sum_{i=1}^ny_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2$?

Comment: Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that take on values $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ and $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$ respectively with equal probabilities $1/n$. Then, your question effectively asks whether $E[X]=E[Y]$ and var$(X) = $ var$(Y)$ suffices to guarantee that the two random variables have the _same_ distribution. Ponder whether such a result is plausible...

Comment: It's a simple matter to construct data sets (i.e. *multisets*) for which the first $k$ moments are the same but which data sets are not identical, for *any* $k$ (though admittedly it gets tedious for large $k$; I have constructed cases up to the ninth moment before, for example, and if I had reason to, could progress further). A number of questions on site deal with the related problem of whether *all moments* - an infinite sequence - are sufficient to characterize a distribution. The answer turns out to be "not in general"  ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... and specific counterexamples are known (and some are described on site). The basic test is "does the MGF exist in a neighborhood of 0?" -- if it does then the moment sequence identifies the distribution, but if it doesn't then you may have more than one distribution with the same moment sequence.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled why this has so many upvotes?

Comment: Did you even consider what happens if you permute the terms in a sequence?

Answer (score 28):

No.

$$ x = (1,1,1,-3) $$
$$ y = (-1,-1,-1,3) $$

$$\sum x_i = \sum y_i = 0$$
$$ \sum x_i^2 = \sum y_i^2 =12$$

Comment: Both are multisets, not sets.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: the OP's notation suggested to me that he is interested in vectors or sequences, not sets as such.

Comment: Here is the counterexample for *sets*: $X=\{1,2,3,-4\}$ and $Y=\{-1,2,-3,4\}$.

Comment: @StephanKolassas Yes, you are right. Sorry for the clunky notation. Im changing it to sequences.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: a set example closer to you original might be $\{1,2,-3\}$ and $\{-1,-2,3\}$

Comment: "the OP's notation suggested to me that *he* is interested": our gender biases are showing.

Comment: @GregMartin: I'm a Bayesian. 90% of people I have dealt with in person in math/stats were male. Unless someone has a decidedly female nick, I'll go with my priors.

Comment: @Henry: Take any sequence that adds up to zero, where positive and negative numbers don't occur in pairs. (a, b, -a-b) and (-a, -b, a+b).

Comment: @StephanKolassa: First of all, I'll bet any amount of money you want that your 90% figure is too high. Already that is your implicit bias showing. Second, there is no need whatsoever to select a gender at all. Third, the environment in STEM is unwelcoming to women, and your "algorithm" makes that worse, and that's harmful. That should matter to you, much more than "yay I guess right a lot".

Answer (score 20):

**No!** You need $n$ polynomial equations.

If I remember correctly, given a set of $n$ *distinct* real numbers $\mathcal Y :=\{y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n\}$, the following system of $n$ polynomial equations

$$\begin{array}{rl} x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n &= c_1\\ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \dots + x_n^2 &= c_2\\ \vdots \\ x_1^n + x_2^n + \dots + x_n^n &= c_n\end{array}$$

where

$$c_k := y_1^k + y_2^k + \dots + y_n^k$$

has $n!$ solutions, namely, all $n!$ **permutations** of the $n$ distinct elements of $\mathcal Y$. One can use algebraic geometry to prove this. I vaguely recall this being related to [moment problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem).

---

#### Example

Let $\mathcal Y := \{1,3,6\}$. Intersecting the plane with the sphere,

$$\begin{array}{rl} x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &= 10\\ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 &= 46\end{array}$$

we obtain a circle on the plane, as depicted below

[image]

However, intersecting these two with the **cubic surface**,

$$\begin{array}{rl} x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &= 10\\ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 &= 46\\ x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3 &= 244\end{array}$$

we obtain the $3!=6$ permutations of the elements of $\mathcal Y$, which are colored in red

[image]

If we plot the quadratic and the cubic surfaces, but not the plane,

[image]

and, from another point of view, we have what looks like a stylish hat

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3751198/339790

Answer (score 11):

To consider an even more basic counterexample. What happens if you simply reorder your sequence? Take $x = (0,1)$ and $y = (1,0)$. (I assume you're talking about sequences, so above $x \neq y$; of course, as sets, $\{0,1\} = \{1,0\}$.)

Answer (score 3):

There are many examples. Here's the first in a long sequence:
$$
(1,4,6,7) \quad (2,3,5,8).
$$
This comes from the first eight entries in the Thue Morse sequence (third line below). The fourth line specifies two sets of eight numbers with the same sum, sum of squares and sum of cubes.

```
AB 
AB BA 
ABBA BAAB  
ABBABAAB BAABABBA
...
```

[The Prouhet-Tarry-Escott problem and generalized Thue-Morse sequences](http://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/joc/content/vols/0007/0001/a005/). J. Comb. 7 (2016), no. 1, 117--133, [Bolker, Ethan D. and Offner, Carl and Richman, Robert and Zara, Catalin]

Here's the preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6756

Answer (score 2):

Something interesting. On all $3 \times 3$ magic squares, the sums of the top and bottom rows is the same (of course) but, also, the sums of the squares of the top and bottom rows is the same. For example

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
   8 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
   1 & 5 & 9 \\
\hline
   6 & 7 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{array}

$8 + 3 + 4 = 6 + 7 + 2 = 15$

$8^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 = 6^2 + 7^2 + 2^2 = 89$

Also

$8 + 1 + 6 = 4 + 9 + 2 = 15$

$8^2 + 1^2 + 6^2 = 4^2 + 9^2 + 2^2 = 101$

This seems to work for some families of larger order magic squares, but I haven't been able to prove it.

Comment: Is this still a magic square if I swap row 2 and 3? If so, then your statement *the sums of the squares of the top and bottom rows is the same* does not hold. $1^2+5^2+9^2 = 107 \neq 89$

Comment: @Therkel. No it's not. the diagonals have to also sum to 15 (or whatever).

Comment: Using [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1790810/339790) I wrote last May, you can easily prove it for $3 \times 3$ magic squares. I am tempted to post a question on this. Do I have your permission?

Comment: The sum of the Hadamard product of the 1st and 2nd rows $$8 + 3 \cdot 5 + 4 \cdot 9 = 59$$ is also equal to the sum of the Hadamard product of the 2nd and 3rd rows $$6 + 5 \cdot 7 + 9 \cdot 2 = 59$$

Comment: The sums of the squares of the 1st and 3rd *columns* are also equal.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo - sure