# Confusion on applying Newton formulae (not Newton's method) technique in finding roots

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots, nonlinear-system, symmetric-polynomials

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751197/reference-for-a-real-algebraic-geometry-problem), Alexandre Eremenko outlines a method to find solutions to systems of equations of the form:

$$\begin{cases} \sum_i x_i = c_1 \\ \;\vdots \\ \sum_i x_i^n = c_n \end{cases}$$

I tried this method, but ended up with a wrong result. Suppose I have:

$$\begin{cases} x_1 + x_2 = 1 \\ x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 3\end{cases}$$

In the language of the Wikipedia article linked in the post, this is $p_1 = 1$ and $p_2 = 3$. Thus if $e_i$ is the $i$th elementary symmetric polynomial, we know that $e_1 = 1$ and $2e_2 = p_1^2 - p_2 = -2$, thus:

$$\begin{cases} e_1 = 1 \\ e_2 = -1 \end{cases}$$

According to Alexandre, the solutions $(x_1,x_2)$ are roots of the polynomial:

$$x^2 + x - 1$$

but these roots are in fact $(-\varphi,-\phi)$ (where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio and $\phi$ its conjugate), when the answer should be $(\varphi,\phi)$. What went wrong?

Comment: I think it should be $x^2-x-1,$ since the sum of the roots is $1.$

Comment: How did you obtain $e_1 = -1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand a factored (monic) polynomial, you can see the coefficients in terms of the roots. In degree $2$,
$$
(x - r_1)(x - r_2) = x^2 - (r_1 + r_2)x + (r_1r_2) = x^2 + a_1x + a_0.
$$
Notice that
$$
-a_1 = r_1 + r_2 = e_1(r_1, r_2)
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
+\!a_0 = r_1r_2 = e_2(r_1, r_2).
$$

*Note the alternating sign!* The general formula, [often attributed to Viète](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Vieta%27s_formulas), looks like
$$
(-1)^k a_{n-k} = e_k(r_1, \dots, r_n)
\qquad
\text{for }
k = 1, \dots, n.
$$

In your case, your polynomial turns out to be
$$
x^2 - x - 1
$$
with roots $\{\varphi, \phi\}$.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected an alternating sign based on other examples that turned out wrong, but I was having trouble seeing why it should be true.