# Easier way to solve equation systems of $a+b+c+\cdots{}= 1$, $a^2 + b^2 + c^2+\cdots{}=2$ and so on without having to crunch massive expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

I study at below college level. I have been trying to solve certain systems of equations involving $n$ equations of $n$ unknowns. For example, for $2$ unknowns, the problem is
\begin{align} 
a^{\phantom{1}} + b^{\phantom{1}} &= 1 \\ 
a^2 + b^2 &= 2 \\ 
a^3 + b^3 &={} ?
\end{align}
This can be solved with elementary algebra and/or WolframAlpha. You can generalize this to more unknowns:
\begin{align} 
a^{\phantom{1}} + b^{\phantom{1}} + c^{\phantom{1}} &= 1 \\ 
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 &= 2 \\ 
a^3 + b^3 + c^3 &= 3 \\ 
a^4 + b^4 + c^4 &={} ? 
\end{align}
with the same restraint: $n$ unknowns, $n$ equations, in each equation the powers of each variable is the same, and the pattern is clear.

Now, I, off of only the first $3$ cases (including the trivial case $a = 1$, find $a^2$) made a conjecture about the result (the missing value of the final expression). Since this is such a random guess at the value, and so many functions could meet just the first few data points, I want to solve the version with $4$ unknowns, just to see whether the conjecture's true.

However, this is very difficult. The expansions quickly get out of hand and not even WolframAlpha can do it. I want a way to at least get the solving process under control. Usually, one'd generate equations and use those to solve for things like $a \cdot b^3$, but here the issue is that just setting up the equations is a task too difficult. Is there a way to elegantly solve the system? I don't mind trading in time for maybe some more difficult math.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3751197/339790)

Comment: There’s a whole theory developed around symmetric polynomials (polynomials that remain unchanged when you swap variables). For a given number of variables, there are different [special bases for the polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) of a given degree: elementary polys, complete polys, power-sum polys **(the ones in your question)**, and there are somewhat complicated [identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities) transforming between the bases.

Comment: See "Newton's identities" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, Mathematica can solve your equations. The
code

```
x/.Solve[{a+b+c==1, a^2+b^2+c^2==2, a^3+b^3+c^3==3,
     a^4+b^4+c^4==x},{a,b,c,x}] //InputForm
```

returns the result $\,x=25/6\,$ with

```
{25/6, 25/6, 25/6, 25/6, 25/6, 25/6}
```

The key idea for an elegant solution is to use [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities). As Wikipedia states

> In mathematics, Newton's identities, also known as the Girard–Newton formulae, give relations between two types of symmetric polynomials, namely between power sums and elementary symmetric polynomials.

Thus, we are given the power symmetric polynomials
$$ p_1 = a+b+c = 1,\\ p_2 = a^2+b^2+c^2 = 2,\\
p_3 = a^3+b^3+c^3 = 3. $$
Use Newton's identities to find the elementary symmetric polynomials to get
$$ e_1 = p_1 = 1, \\
e_2 = (p_1^2-p_2)/2 = -\frac12, \\
e_3 = \left(\frac12 p_1^2 - \frac32 p_1p_2 + p_3\right)/3 = \frac16. $$
There is a recursion for the $\,p_i\,$ given by
$$ p_{i+3} = p_{i+2}e_1 -p_{i+1}e_2 +p_{i}e_3. $$
Apply this for $\,i=1\,$ gives the result
$$ p_4 = p_3\cdot(1) -p_2\cdot(-1/2) +p_1\cdot(1/6) = \frac{25}6. $$

---

You need to use the relation between the
first $\,n\,$ elementary symmetric functions and the
first $\,n\,$ power symmetric functions to solve for
$\,p_{n+1}\,$ given $\,p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n.\,$ All of
the formulas generalize.

However, in the special case were $\,p_i=i\,$ for
$\,i=1,\dots,n\,$ the answer is already given in the
[OEIS sequence A094094](https://oeis.org/A094094)

> Define x[1]...x[n] by the equations Sum_{j=1..n} x[j]^i = i, i=1..n; a(n) = n! * Sum_{j=1..n} x[j]^(n+1).

The entry gives an exponential generating function

> E.g.f.: (1-exp(x/(x-1)))/(1-x)^2.

and also closed form formulas and summations

> a(n) = n!*(n+1-LaguerreL(n,1,1)) = Sum_{k=1..n} (-1)^(k+1)*n!/k!*binomial(n+1,k+1).

Comment: Sorry - I made a mistake. I have rewritten the polynomials - the idea is that there are as many given equations as unknowns.

Comment: Never mind - I made a mistake.

Comment: Do I only need the first 3 elementary symmetric polynomials to continually generate these? My further equations have n variables - would this require the nth elementary symmetric polynomial? Would I need the 4th elementary polynomial (along with 1st, second, third) acting on a, b, c, d to generate the solution for $p_5$?